# Program Testing Coverage with JaCoCo

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jacoco

I am testing a short program using JaCoCo, and I have almost achieved 100% coverage, except this is the only statement I can't seem to test, what test suite can I write to be able to cover the whole program? Attached below is the code. [image: Here is a screenshot of my JaCoCo report]

[image: Pt. 2]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you should attain 100% if you really can't (there are some tricker case than your, which are practically impossible to fix), but in that case, you must simply invoke your `main` with less than 3 args:

```
IglooScore.main(new String[0]);
```

This is equivalent to invoking `java -jar blabla.jar IglooScore.main`

```
IglooScore.main(null);
```

The second should never arise when the JRE launch your program, but this could happen if the `main` was invoked programmatically (from test for instance).

Note that your case is simple:

```
if (args.length != 3)
```

If it is in red, this means that you must check the condition:

- With a test passing an `args` matching `args.length == 3` (covered)
- With a test passing an `args` *not* matching `args.length == 3` (not covered)

You may also have this case:

```
if (args == null || args.length != 3)
```

This means that you must:

- With a test passing an `args` being `null`
- With a test passing an `args` not null and matching `args.length == 3`
- With a test passing an `args` not null and *not* matching `args.length == 3`

In worse case, it may help to split the expression on several line to display the uncovered line, eg:

```
if (args == null ||
    args.length != 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your test class the case when you call your `main()` with arguments *less than or greater than `3`* :

```
String [] testInput = new String[2];
testInput[0] = "invalidInput"; // don't worry this wouldn't reach the point to throw ParseException
testInput[1] = "invalidInputAgain";
new IglooScore1().main(testInput); // line of code to test
```